# Duplicate tags [scrollview] and [android-scrollview]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

[scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollview) and [android-scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-scrollview) are about the same thing. The latter is newer and less used, but has a better name in my opinion, so I would prefer it to stay.

Comment: They are not duplicates. The Scrollview tag wiki has been [incorectly edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7257042/revisions), hence it looks confusing. If you see the questions for [tag:scrollview], this tag is used to indicate the generic view on various platforms.

Comment: Ok, so the other option is to move 1800 questions from [tag:scrollview] to [tag:android-scrollview], fix the scrollview description and add a reference to android-scrollview.

Comment: The `[scrollview]` tag was updated to make it more generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not. There is `UIScrollView` and `NSScrollView` in Objective-C, for example. And tagging a question about them with [scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollview) is normal. Note that in this case it is no longer synonym of [android-scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-scrollview).

Comment: I suggested a tag wiki modification to make `[scrollview]` more generic.